# Achievements menu: Can you tell me why I got reputation?

Tags: feature-request, top-bar, achievements-dialog

The achievements drop-down menu in the new top bar shows me when a question/answer earns me reputation and how much, and that's great, but I don't know what caused that to happen. I'd like to know why I received reputation: was it an upvote? An accepted answer? An accepted edit? If I have the list of reputation values in my head I can figure it out, but it would help me to see it somewhere in the drop-down, even as title text on hover.

---

**Edit:**

It sounds like the items in the menu can roll up multiple events, and that's why it doesn't show the event there. How about adding a link to my reputation tab to the menu so I can quickly get to a breakdown?

Comment: The formula is relatively simple: +10 = upvote on an answer. +5 = upvote on a question. +2 = an accepted edit. +15 = an accepted answer. -2 = a downvote on a question or answer

Comment: Trouble is it can be more than 1; e.g. upvote and accept

Comment: You can view the exact changes in your [reputation history](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1864167/jeroen-vannevel?tab=reputation). Go to your own profile for your own changes, obviously.

Comment: Thanks for the dupe. I figured someone must have asked already, but I couldn't for the life of me find it.

Comment: I had this question as well, and I was glad to see it had already been answered. Can this question be linked in the primary How Does Reputation Work? question? This question is really hard to find while searching.

Comment: Also, I think this question is more valuable than the question it is a duplicate of. This question has two answers, both of which are very good and helpful, and the title of the question makes it clear what exactly is being asked. None of these things are true for the original question. I feel that this question should be marked as superior, and the older one should be marked as duplicate, or simply less helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The achievements menu is meant as a quick overview of what is happening in the context of your account. It doesn't need to be bloated up with more information that is available in more detail elsewhere.

In the specific instance of reputation, you can get a full breakdown of all activity by going to [your profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current) (clicking on your avatar/badge count in the top bar) and then clicking on the ["reputation" tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current/?tab=reputation) half way down the page.

This will give you a full breakdown of all reputation changes including the type of reputation change and the question/answer/other action that the reputation change occurred on.

Comment: Question edited. How about adding a link to my reputation tab to the menu so I can quickly get to a breakdown?

Answer (score 1):

> How about adding a link to my reputation tab to the menu so I can quickly get to a breakdown?

Already exists. Click one of the icons.

[image: icons]

Comment: Right. Each site has its own profile. I see it now. Okay, we're done here, then! :) (Thanks.)

Comment: Oh, except, if I've only gotten reputation today on a single Stack Exchange, I don't have those icons. Does the link go somewhere else? Or is it missing?