# Could Achievement reports be a little clearer in the dropdown?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, top-bar, achievements-dialog

Question:

[image]

Does any of that mean anything to you? I ask this because without knowing why the reputation was gained or lost, it's mostly useless to me. Because when I click the link that is the question, I get taken to the question, but there's no information on that question as to what may have changed (obviously)

Now, I know all I have to do is run to `?tab=reputation` to see the detailed breakdown, but I'm curious as to the reason why the one word breakdown can't exist here.

I had to remind myself that the `-50` was a Bounty that got collected, and that my latest +5 was due to an upvote on an older question. `Accept`, `Upvote`, `Bounty`, I just wonder if we can't have that status in the Achievements drop down as well.

I may be crazy though

Comment: ([this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214579/achievements-menu-can-you-tell-me-why-i-got-reputation) is a better dupe, but closed as dupe by itself)